# Making a throwable response to exception handling in R

Tags: r, exception, types

I've turned my hand to R after many years of Java/C++. I am struggling to protect my operational flow using exception handling. Perhaps, I am looking at this with too much of a Java hat on.

Essentially, I am looking for a throw operator at the start of a function if a partiular argument to that function is incorrectly typed. An example for the structure (not functioning code) I am looking for:

```
myFunction <- function(someListArgument) {
    if(class(someListArgument) != "List") {
        throw(paste("Argument not a list: ", class(someListArgument)))
    }
}

tryCatch({myFunction(c("whoops!"))},
    error = function(cond) {},
    ....
)
```

I would really like the compartmentalisation of code as I am writing an R->MySQL DBMS API and I would like to keep well controlled and informative error reporting if incorrect datatypes are provided.

Comment: help("stopifnot")

Comment: also consider running `error = function(cond) browser()` and using `dput(cond)` to examine the object that is produced during error handling more carefully. This will perhaps allow you, for example, to use `grep` on `cond$message` to throw more helpful errors

Comment: Thanks, both. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Further to this, and forgive me if I've missed something in the literature, how do I know the nature of an error of a core/packaged function?  e.g., con<-dbConnect(.....) in some languages there would be some error distinction between a lack of Network and an incorrect password from which I can catch using the appropriate thrown argument (very Java, I know).

Comment: @AnthonyNash There is no general answer to this question. Errors are function specific.